# Using a for loop with beautiful soup and if statements to populate a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, beautifulsoup

**Goal:** The goal of my project is to use `BeautifulSoup` aka `bs4` to scrape only necessary data from an `HTML` file and import it into excel. The html file is heavily formatted so unfortunately I haven't been able to tailor more common solutions to my needs.

**What I have tried:** I have been able to parse the HTML file to the point where I am only pulling the tables I need, and I am able to detect every column of data and print it. In example, if there are a total of 18 columns and 3 rows of data, the code will output 54 times with each piece of table data going from row 1 col 1 to row 3 col 18.

My code is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd


url =
output = 

#define table error to detect only tables with extractable data
def iserror(func, *args, **kw):
    try:
        func(*args, **kw)
        return False
    except Exception:
        return True

#read the html
with open(url) as html_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'html.parser')

#table = soup.find_all('table')
all_tables = soup.find_all('table')
#print(len(table))

df = pd.DataFrame( columns=(pks_col_names))
col_list = []
table_list = []

for tnum, tables in enumerate(all_tables):
    if iserror(all_tables[tnum].tbody): #Finds table with data
        table = tables.findAll('tr')
        #Loops through rows of each data table
        for rnum, row in enumerate(table):
            table_row = table[rnum].findAll('td')

            if len(table_row)==17: 
        #Loops through columns of each data table
                for col in table_row: 
                        col_list.append(col.string)
          
            else:
                pass
            

        
    else:
        pass
```

**Example of data output currently achieved**

row 1 column 1 (first string in list) 
row 1 column 2 
row 1 column 3 ... 
row 3 column 17 
row 3 column 18 (last string in list)

The current code creates a single list with the data outputted above, though I am unable to figure out a way to convert that list into a pandas dataframe tying each list output to the appropriate row/column. Could anyone provide ideas on how to do this or how to otherwise rework my code to import this data into a dataframe?

Comment: Did you forget to add the values for `url` and `output` in your code snippet? Also, `pks_col_names` will raise a `NameError` since it isn't defined

Comment: use `panda`'s `.read_html()` to parse the tables. Then you can construch into single dataframe and use `.to_csv()` or `.to_excel()`. Also, It's hard to help when you don't provide the url.

Comment: Hi thank you both for your help. I redacted the url because it was just an mhtml file linked to my desktop (downloaded as an mthml file). I apologize if that was confusing. Unfortunately, the original file has confidential information, and I am not savvy enough to be able to create a dummy mhtml file for testing purposes.

Regarding using pandas.read_html, will that work with really messy data? I used beautiful soup as I needed to use certain logic to define what tables to pull in a systematic way.

Comment: [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) will extract all tables into a list: `df = pd.read_html('filename.mhtml')`, then find where in the list the table you need is located: `df[0]`, `df[1]`, etc. Then you can write that table to a file, eg `df[3].to_csv('filename.csv')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's all messed up: your function `iserror` does in fact check if there's no error (and i don't think it works at all). what you call tables are rows and you don't need to `enumerate`

as you haven't provided the data, i made only rough tests. but it's a bit cleaner

```
row_list = []
for table in all_tables:
    if is_ok(table.tbody): #Finds table with data
        rows = table.findAll('tr')
        #Loops through rows of each data table
        for row in rows:
            cols = row.findAll('td')
            col_list = []
            if len(cols)==17: 
                #Loops through columns of each data table
                for col in cols: 
                    col_list.append(col.string)
                row_list.append(col_list)

df = pd.DataFrame(row_list, columns=(pks_col_names))
```

Comment: Hi Diggus, thank you so much for your help.  I changed is_ok to iserror (based on my function name) but the rest worked perfectly. I apologize about the code being messed up, I'm still an amateur at best in Python. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help. I was able to achieve the desired data frame and the final code looks like this:

```
url = 'insert url here'

#define table error to detect only tables with extractable data
def iserror(func, *args, **kw):
    try:
        func(*args, **kw)
        return False
    except Exception:
        return True

#All tables
all_tables = soup.findAll('table')

#Define column names
pks_col_names = ['TBD','Trade Date', 'Settle Date', 'Source', 'B/S', 'Asset Name', 'Security Description',
'Ticker','AccountID','Client Name','Shares','Price','Amount','Comms',
'Fees', 'Payout %','Payout']


row_list = []
for table in all_tables:
    if iserror(table.tbody): #Finds table with data
        rows = table.findAll('tr')
        #Loops through rows of each data table
        for row in rows:
            cols = row.findAll('td')
            col_list = []
            if len(cols)==17: 
                #Loops through columns of each data table
                for col in cols: 
                    col_list.append(col.string)

                row_list.append(col_list)

df = pd.DataFrame(row_list, columns=(pks_col_names))

df.to_csv(output, index=False, encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
```